# stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I think the time has come for me to step down as a community moderator here. I never ended up being as active as I intended to be, and now I have a [new job](http://fedoramagazine.org/first-thoughts-as-fedora-project-leader/) which is going to leave even less spare time. (I do plan to stay active and answer questions, particularly around Fedora!)

Comment: Congrats on your new job. Sounds exciting!

Comment: @slm Thanks — it is and will be! I had intended to write something a little more eloquent here, but... it's a busy day, turns out. :)

Comment: Congrats and I hope to see you around ;)

Comment: I know the feeling, I kind of stopped being active as I moved into development, hopefully things go well for you.

Answer (score 26):

On behalf of the team here at The Stack Exchange Subterranean Lair, I'd like to thank you for all the work you've put in over the years and wish you all the best in your new job!

We'll kick off an election for your replacement next week, and I'll remove your diamond at its conclusion.

Comment: Geez Shog, nobody's supposed to know about the secret S.E.S.L. headquarters. Now we gotta up and move the Lair again. *sigh*

Comment: @RobertCartaino Is this what prompted the [#stackDCmove](https://twitter.com/hashtag/stackDCmove?src=hash)? 'cause you know the new location is being leaked (even without help from Shog) in geotags right?

Answer (score 22):

As a member of the general public¹ and the user-base you have served on this site I would like to publicly thank you for your years of volunteer effort. I wish you all the best in your new endeavors and hope they include lots of 'nixy stuff.

<sub>¹ Unlike some [liars] hiding in their subterranean lairs I am not ashamed to broadcast this message from the open!</sub>