# Can I nominate other people?

Tags: support, moderation, election

The Moderators Nomination have just begin and I'm so excited about this event

my questions are:

- How can I know the moderators of the last year?
- Can I nominate a moderator ?
- Can I nominate other people or I could only nominate myself ?

Comment: Much of this is explained on the [election page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination), in the bar on the right side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current moderators are listed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators and they were elected during the previous election (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/1). As you see in the Community Bulletin, [mattdm is stepping down](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/stepping-down-as-moderator).

You can only nominate yourself to run; that's actually fairly common in nominations for elected office. Nominating yourself also says you're willing to do the job.

If you want someone besides yourself to run, you have to get him/her to volunteer (nominate him/herself).

Comment: The chatter in [chat] the other day leads me to think quite a few people would support _you_ if you were to nominate yourself. Have you considered it?