# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Unix & Linux's [2nd moderator election](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: slm] [image: terdon]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please also bid a fond farewell to mattdm, who is [hanging up his diamond hat](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/stepping-down-as-moderator) after [3 years of service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/1).

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6185854364024832/0).

Comment: Congratulations guys, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your votes of confidence, I'll do my best to not disappoint! Congrats to Terdon too, he'll be an awesome mod!

Comment: See https://github.com/OpenTechStrategies/openstv if like most people on this site you don't have access to a _windows_ or _mac_ machine.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas On this site, I expect everyone to `apt-get install openstv` or `pkg_add openstv` or similar. Reminder: the command is `wget -O unix-2.blt http://unix.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/2 && openstv-run-election MeekSTV unix-2.blt`

Comment: I actually couldn't find a package for my distro (Gentoo), but the github code includes a `runElection.py` that seems to match up with `openstv-run-election`

Comment: Congratulations you guys. Thank you for shouldering the extra responsibilities for the community.

Comment: I would like to extend my congratulations to terdon and my sorta kinda Friend slm. Good LUCK guys!!!

Comment: Thank you all, we won't let you down.